# ZendFramework 2 AuthService available in ViewFile

Tags: view, zend-framework2

I wanted to get something like this (this is from controller)

```
$authService = $this->serviceLocator->get('auth_service');
if ($authService->hasIdentity()) {
    [...]
} else {
    [...]
}
```

in the view file (*.phtml) co i can display login or logout link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an `identity()` view helper already available in the framework, to use it you need to map your auth service instance to `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService`, which you can do by aliasing it to your `auth_service` in your module.config.php, eg..

```
<?php
return array(
    //..
    'service_manager' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => 'auth_service',
        ),
    ),
    // ..
);
```

The helper has no parameters, it simply returns the identity or null, so for your example of testing if user is authenticated, in your view, you'd use ...

```
<?php
if ($this->identity()) : ?>
    Logged In User
<?php else : ?>
    Guest
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom [View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html) to expose methods from the AuthService to the view. For an example, take a look at the way [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/View/Helper/ZfcUserIdentity.php) created their view helper. I would point out, however, that they're injecting the AuthenticationService into the view helper. This was done through a configuration closure in the [Module.php](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/Module.php) file.